# Fetching data using one-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, models, one-to-many

I am new to ror. I have 2 tables for group (called 'ab') and sub-group(called 'cd').Each group has several sub-groups.I have defined belongs_to and has_many relationship.

Model ab.rb

```
class Ab < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many:cds
end
```

Model cd.rb

```
class Cd < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ab
end
```

ab and cd have 2 columns each called title and Dscr.Do I have to create a join table (ab_cd_join_table)

I want to display a particular group and its sub-groups in a view.

The controller for the view

```
class DisplayController < ApplicationController

    def index
         @ab = Ab.find_by_title("XXXXXX")
             @cds = @ab.cds
                 for cd in @cds
                 logger.info cd.title
        end
```

I am using this in the view.

display view

```
<%= @ab.title %>
```

I don't know how to display the title and Dscr of different sub-groups belonging to the  group = "XXXXXX"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you're asking for is this in the view:

```
<% @ab.cds.each do |cd| %>
<h1><%= cd.title %></h1>
<p><%= cd.description %></p>
<% end %>
```

and this in the controller:

```
@ab = Ab.find_by_title("XXXXXX")
```

That way you will display all cds for the ab-model matching "XXXXXX".

**Update:**
For belongs_to and has_many to work the model with belongs_to needs to have a column for the one that has has_many. In this case Cd needs to have a column named ab_id.

```
rails g migration add_ab_id_to_cds ab_id:integer
```

cd.ab_id needs to be the id of the corresponding Ab model.

```
cds = Cd.where(<something>)
cds.each do |cd|
  cd.ab_id = @ab.id
  cd.save
end
```

This maybe should be set upon creation of a Cd object, but just to test it out you can do like this.

Comment: Hello Frans, I tried the change in the view and I am getting this error message SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: cds.ab_id: SELECT "cds".* FROM "cds"  WHERE "cds"."ab_id" = 1

Comment: Do you have a column named ab_id in Cd? You need that so that the Cd knows to which Ab it belongs. `rails g migration add_ab_id_to_cds ab_id:integer` should be the code to create the needed migration. And after that you run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where you asked if you needed a join table. Well, you don't. Just an ab_id in the model that has "belongs_to".

Comment: Frans I created the column ab_id in cd.The error is gone but i don't see any data being fetched.Yes,I have used exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Ah, it won't work for existing records, as the ab_id will be empty. The ab_id needs to be set to the corresponding id of the model it belongs to. I'll update my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do I have to create a join table (ab_cd_join_table)

> No in this case you don't need a join table, instead you need to add
>   ab_id column in cds table.(the foreign key column should be present in
>   table of model defining belongs_to assiciation)

Displaying subgroup title in view

```
<% @ab.cds.each |sub_group| %>
<%= sub_group.title -%>
<%= sub_group.description -%>
<%end%>
```

Also, if you alwas need sub_groups with group then load them in one query by using include option in find like

```
@ab = Ab.find_by_title("XXXXXX",:include=> :cds)
```

now you don't need to calculate cds explicitly just use the view code mentioned above

Comment: Hello Naren. I am trying something similar to what you said.

Comment: does this solution help? or you need anything more?